# Better Linq GroupBy

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

We are working on an advertising platform and writing the one big query thats responsible for serving ads, there is a few criteria to serve an ad to consumer, one of thos criteria is the Campaign Daily Budget, so what we are doing is we are grouping by Individual Ads to get the impressions and the consumed cost and then we group by Campaign, resulting in the following query:

```
  (from a in AdCreative
       join h in AdHit on a.ID equals h.AdID into gh
       join l in AdGroup_Location on a.AdGroupID equals l.AdGroupID into gj
       from subloc in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
       from subhits in gh.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where a.AdDimensionID == 7 && 
             (subloc == null || subloc.LocationID == 23)
       select new {
           ID = a.ID,
           Name = a.Name,
           Spent = (subhits.AdDimension != null) ? ((double)subhits.AdDimension.Credit / 1000 ) : 0,
           CampaignID = a.AdGroup.Campaign.ID,
           CampaignName = a.AdGroup.Campaign.Name,
           CampaignBudget = a.AdGroup.Campaign.DailyBudget

       })
    .GroupBy(adgroup => adgroup.ID)
    .Select(adgroup => new {
        ID = adgroup.Key,
        Name = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Spent = adgroup.Sum(q =>  q.Spent),
        CampaignID = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignID,
        CampaignName = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignName,
        CampaignBudget = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignBudget,
    })
    .GroupBy(q => q.CampaignID)
    .Select(campaigngroup => new {
      CampaignID = campaigngroup.Key,
      DailyBudget = campaigngroup.FirstOrDefault().CampaignBudget,
      Spent = campaigngroup.Sum(q => q.Spent),
      Ads = campaigngroup.GroupBy(q => q.ID).Select(adgroup => new {
        ID = adgroup.Key,
        Name  = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Spent = adgroup.FirstOrDefault().Spent
    })
    })
```

[image: Results]

It works fine as you see in the results in the screenshots, however when I inspected the generate SQL query I got [***402*** lines of SQL code](https://gist.github.com/3865826). How could that be? is there something I could do to enhance the code

Comment: LINQ is built for ease-of-use, not generating succint queries. :(

Comment: a) what do you mean be "how could that be?"? b) what do you mean by "enhance the code"?

Comment: @AakashM i mean the resulting sql query is too complex, there might be a better way to express it in linq to produce simpler sql query

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I notice is that in the very last `GroupBy` you don't aggregate but only show `Key` and first values. I think you might as well `Select` `q.Id`, `q.Name`, and `q.Spent` there.

It would make sense that two `GroupBy`s should suffice since you show two levels of aggregation (twice `Spent`).

Comment: nice, that now 243 lines of code, any further optimization i could do?

Comment: Maybe put the items that you select by `adgroup.FirstOrDefault()` etc. directly into the `GroupBy`. (`GroupBy x => new { x.A, x.B, ... }`).